# How easy to get started on making apps for Mac?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I've done some delving into AppleScript but I'm interested in how difficult and long it would take to make semi-useful Mac apps.

What really good resources besides Apple Documentation?

Comment: or list some available options for programming on Mac - Leopard style apps that look good and most up-to-date coding...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"Cocoa Programming For Mac OS X" from Aaron Hillegass. Nice book that gives you an introduction into Objective C and Cocoa programming.

Comment: That book took me from knowing nothing at all about programming in Cocoa to producing a rather nice Jigsaw application in the space of about a month and a half. I thoroughly endorse stesch's choice.

Answer (score 2):

As stesch said "Cocoa Programming For Mac OS X" is the best book available for an introduction into Cocoa and Objective-C. However if you already know python or ruby you can easily make great looking applications using their cocoabindings.

Answer (score 1):

"how difficult and long it would take" depends on what you already know. If you can program in C, Java, or C++ with a good understanding of object-orientation and vague idea of how the model-view-controller design paradigm works, then you will be in good stead.

Come up with a small but interesting idea that will keep you motivated to continue learning Cocoa/Objective-C because the learning curve can be steep at the start.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make widgets, they are actually little web pages, often with JavaScript.